# Inserting values into mysql tables from a csv file with null values causing error

Tags: mysql, csv, load-data-infile

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

```
"Jared","D","James","111111100","1966-10-10","123 Peachtree, Atlanta, GA","M","85000.00","null","6"
"Brad","C","Knight","111111103","1968-02-13","176 Main St., Atlanta, GA","M","44000.00","111111100","6"
```

I am trying to make entry into a table with this command:

```sql
load data infile '/var/lib/mysql-files/employee.dat' 
into table employee 
fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"';
```

This is resulting in an error:

> ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails `` (`employee`, CONSTRAINT `employee_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`superssn`) REFERENCES `employee` (`ssn`)) ``

Table employee is created like

```
DROP TABLE employee;
CREATE TABLE employee (
  fname    varchar(15) not null, 
  minit    varchar(1),
  lname    varchar(15) not null,
  ssn      char(9),
  bdate    date,
  address  varchar(50),
  sex      char,
  salary   decimal(10,2),
  superssn char(9),
  dno      integer(4),
  primary key (ssn),
  foreign key (superssn) references employee(ssn),
  foreign key (dno) references department(number)
);
```

The same load data infile command worked for some other data files with the same format

**I think it's most likely the null value in quotes that is causing the issue and MySQL is trying to insert the null as a string resulting in a foreign key violation.**

What could I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: There is no NULL value in shown data. There is 4-char string value whose value is `'null'`. Study https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: Got it. I modified the "NULL" to \N, and then it worked. May be you can post this as an answer and I will accept